# echo the created directory name

Tags: shell, shell-script

I'm trying to echo the new directory that I'm creating in the script.

```
BACKUP_DIR=`mkdir /tmp/"$TICKET_NUM"_EAR_BACKUP_"$(date "+%Y%m%d")"`
echo $BACKUP_DIR
```

But, the newly created directory is not echoed in the screen. Anything Im missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You are echoing the output of `mkdir`, because you are executing the command via backtick operators `` ` `` and assigning the result to the `BACKUP_DIR` variable.

The output of `mkdir` will blank.

You should try something like this:

```
BACKUP_DIR=/tmp/${TICKET_NUM}_EAR_BACKUP_`date "+%Y%m%d"`
echo "${BACKUP_DIR}"
mkdir "${BACKUP_DIR}"
```